# tricky Pointer arithmetic in C: **k

Tags: c, pointers

Assume k is a pointer to an integer in C.

For the expression **k, when we try to evaluate this on the right side of an assignment operator("="), would the value be illegal?

Here is my thought:

**k is actually *(*k). When we dereference k, we get the value of an integer. Then we try to dereference an integer, which is an illegal operation.

But my textbook says this expression on the right side is actually legal.

Why so?

Comment: `*` could be multiply if there is another int on the left to it.

Comment: `"Assume k is a pointer to an integer in C."` OK, ... `"For the expression **k,.:` Wait... If `k` is a pointer to `int`, `*k` is an `int` and `**k` is nonsense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your thought is (fundamentally) correct.  I would suggest providing the code the textbook says is correct.

Comment: You should show the **exact text** shown in your textbook.

Answer (score 5):

The C 2018 standard says, in clause 6.5.3.2, paragraph 2, “The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.” If `k` is a pointer to an integer, then `*k` is an integer, which is not a pointer type, so it cannot be the operand of a unary `*` operator. Thus an expression such as `x = **k` violates this rule.

The rule ins 6.5.3.2 2 is a constraint, meaning that a conforming compiler is required to produce a diagnostic message for and that the C standard does not define the behavior.

Technically, a C compiler could, in addition to issuing the diagnostic message, accept the expression and define as it pleases. I am not aware of any that do so, and no common compiler does so.

It is possible the characters `**k` might appear in some larger expression where they do not both act as unary `*` operators, such as in `x = y**k`, which is equivalent to `x = y * *k`, in which the first `*` is a binary multiplication operator. You should show the **exact text** shown in your textbook.

Comment: A quick test using `-std=gnu90` also failed to compile:  `int n=5; int*pN=&n; void*pV=(void*)(**pN);`

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what the standard says, dereferencing an int fundamentally makes no sense.  Let's say the compiler is willing to assume that ints can be converted to directly to pointers (a BIG assumption).  What TYPE of pointer will the compiler assume it is?  The only safe assumption is `void*`.  And dereferencing a `void*` makes no sense because even when assigning to a known type, the **type of pointer** still matters:

```
  unsigned int n = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  void *pN = &n;
  unsigned int fromIntPtr = *(unsigned int*)pN;
  unsigned int fromCharPtr = *(unsigned char*)pN;
  printf("%X\n", fromIntPtr);
  printf("%X\n", fromCharPtr);
```

Output:

```
FFFFFFFF
FF
```

Lacking a type of pointer, the compiler could perhaps infer `unsigned int*` based on the LHS expression.  That's 1) a wildly stupid inference and 2) C doesn't really infer types.  (Shoving a typed RHS into a differently typed LHS value isn't inference :))